# Understanding processor cache usage

Tags: caching, compiler-optimization, cpu-cache

I am trying to understand how the various caches are used in a processor. Lets say I am incrementing each value of a 67 byte array. Lets assume a 32 bit linux OS.

Lets assume the cache line is 64-bytes. Now if I have the following code --

```
add()
{
    unsigned char a[67] = {0};
    for( int i=0; i<67; i++)
        a[i] = a[i] + 4;
}
```

Can someone explain how the processor cache will be used for this function?  If I understand the cache line concept correctly, is 64-bytes of data copied every time the processor wants to copy a byte to L1?

How does the compiler optimize this code to use the cache efficiently?

If the question is complete nonsense, please tell me how.

Answer (score 0):

An exact answer would rely on too many parameters, such as system implementation, etc., but I will try to give my intuition, since it's been a month, and you got nothing.

---

You may already know this, but let me note that `a` has a size of 67 bytes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char a[67] = {0};
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a)); // prints 67
    return 0;
}
```

---

Our cache is 64 bytes, so let's assume that it can hold 64 cells of `a` when it's totally empty.

The loop of your code starts executing, `i` is a variable and let's assume that it's *not* going to be cached, so that we make the answer simpler.

Your code tries to access `a[i]`, so we lookup in the cache, but see nothing (that is called a *cold start*, when cache is empty, i.e. always, at the start of the program, forcing for cache misses).

The first 64 bytes of `a` are going to be copied into the cache, assuming that the OS treats the whole array as one.

You do the addition, but you updated `a[i]`, with i = 0, so if you would access `a[i]` again, its bit would be marked as dirty and the cache lookup would result into a miss.

---

Next loop, we want `a[1]`, we check the cache, hurray!, it's already there, so we have a cache hit. And so on, until we request `a[64]`, which is not in the cache, since the whole array wouldn't fit.

The OS will fetch the `a[64]` and now the question is who will be the victim for replacement, since it may want to fetch `a[65]` and `a[66]` as well.

It chooses its victim(s) with the replacement policy that is in charge, and when we ask for `a[65]`, assuming it was fetched along with `a[64]`, we will have a cache hit.

---

That was a very approximate, somehow inaccurate overview of what would happen, but the point here is to give you the intuition, hope it helped! :)